# Can't install awscli to docker VM

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cli, amazon-ecs

I'm on windows 10 using the docker toolkit to run a VM for docker to run in. I'm trying to push to AWS ECS. I need awscli to do that. I run the command `pip install awscli` and it seems to be successfully installed. But then when I run `aws --version` it says that aws can't be found.

```
$ pip install awscli
Requirement already satisfied: awscli in 
c:\users\matthew\appdata\roaming\python\python35\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML<=3.12,>=3.10 in 
c:\users\matthew\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages 
(from awscli)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils>=0.10 in 
c:\users\matthew\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages 
(from awscli)
Requirement already satisfied: botocore==1.5.56 in 
c:\users\matthew\appdata\roaming\python\python35\site-packages (from awscli)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama<=0.3.7,>=0.2.5 in 
c:\users\matthew\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages 
(from awscli)
Requirement already satisfied: rsa<=3.5.0,>=3.1.2 in 
c:\users\matthew\appdata\roaming\python\python35\site-packages (from awscli)
Requirement already satisfied: s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.9 in 
c:\users\matthew\appdata\roaming\python\python35\site-packages (from awscli)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 in 
c:\users\matthew\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages 
(from botocore==1.5.56->awscli)
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in 
c:\users\matthew\appdata\roaming\python\python35\site-packages (from 
botocore==1.5.56->awscli)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.3 in 
c:\users\matthew\appdata\roaming\python\python35\site-packages (from 
rsa<=3.5.0,>=3.1.2->awscli)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in 
c:\users\matthew\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages 
(from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore==1.5.56->awscli)

$ aws --version
bash: aws: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it must have been a pip vs pip3 issue. I uninstalled awscli and reinstalled it using pip3 and it worked.